# Sort treemap on value and return it as treemap agin.

Tags: java, treemap, key-value-store

i have treemap and i sort it on value with code bellow. how can i get results as treemap again?

```
static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> SortedSet<Map.Entry<K, V>> entriesSortedByValues(
        Map<K, V> map) {
    SortedSet<Map.Entry<K, V>> sortedEntries = new TreeSet<Map.Entry<K, V>>(
            new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Map.Entry<K, V> e1, Map.Entry<K, V> e2) {
                    int res = e1.getValue().compareTo(e2.getValue());
                    return res != 0 ? res : 1;
                }
            });
    sortedEntries.addAll(map.entrySet());
    return sortedEntries;
}
```

Comment: A `TreeMap` is always sorted by key; it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Why are you creating `TreeSet` there instead of a `TreeMap`?

Comment: You have to specify what you expect as key and value in the resulting sorted map. As-is, the question is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a `TreeSet`, whereas, you need to create a `TreeMap`. The comparator which you pass to `TreeMap`, will use the `map` passed as parameter, to fetch the value and compare them.

Change your method to:

```
static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> TreeMap<K, V> entriesSortedByValues(final Map<K, V> map) {
    TreeMap<K, V> sortedEntries = new TreeMap<K, V>(new Comparator<K>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(K o1, K o2) {
        return map.get(o1).compareTo(map.get(o2));
      }
    });
    sortedEntries.putAll(map);
    return sortedEntries;
}
```

Tested with:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
  map.put(1, 3);
  map.put(3, 1);
  map.put(5, 6);
  map.put(2, 10);
  // Prints: {3=1, 1=3, 5=6, 2=10}
  System.out.println(entriesSortedByValues(map));
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does, but it's a trick since the key comparator will get the corresponding values **every time** it is called. Performance wise, it's certainly awful...

Comment: Didn't check your `map.get(o1).compareTo(map.geT(o2))`

Comment: @AbbéRésina Not that much aweful, given that `Map#get` is an `O(1)` operation.

Comment: @RohitJain Isn't it O(logN) ?

Comment: @AbbéRésina Well, what kind of sorting is better than `O(logN)`?

Comment: @RohitJain: `TreeMap.get` performs O(log n) comparisons, each of which now take O(log n), so now your map takes O((log n)^2) time for lookups, which I think is the issue?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I don't see how each comparison is taking `O(log n)`? I do 2 `map.get()` invocation, which is `O(1)` anyways. And then Integer comparison, well which again is `O(1)`. Yeah, if we talk about complex `V` type, then it would be costly..

Comment: Ah, sorry; it depends on the implementation of the backing map.  If it's a TreeMap, then each `map.get` takes O(log n) and my analysis is as described.